# same CSS, different browser outcomes?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this tag, which shows up great in Chrome but as you can see from screenshots looks wrong in Firefox.

```
     html { 
 background-image:url("BackgroundePictureTitleHD.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

THe background picture dimensions are 1366x769.
I am using the  background-size: so I can see the background NO MATTER the browser windows dimension.

This is the correct way to do so right?

[image: Here what the above code looks like in Chrome:]

[image: Here what the above code looks like in Firefox:]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I did noticed that if I changed: background-size: 100% 100%; to background-size:cover; this works.

Answer (score 3):

`body` and `html` don't have a height itself by default, the height is given by the content the they have.

And because to tell the background to have a height of `100%` of its container, and you probably just have a `<p>` inside it does not fill the entire window.

you can give them a height using this rule:

```
body, html {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 100%; 
}
```

And always add the css property without the vendor prefix at the end of your rule to.
It should be (but that's something i need to verify when I'm back home) ignored by browsers that do not support it, so `100% 100%` is the fallback. If this does not work move the `background-size: cover` out of this rule and create a separate one right below it only containing `background-size: cover`.

```
html { 
  background-image:url("BackgroundePictureTitleHD.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: @ProGM yes, I did not see that the `background-size: cover` without vendor prefix was missing. Added it to the answer.

Comment: ;) yeah but now there are two `background-size`

Comment: @ProGM honestly i'm need to check it when back home, but I thought `background-size: cover;` is ignored if not supported by the browser. So `100% 100%` is the fallback which would obviously stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use backstretch: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

It should make it easy and take care of a lot of issues, such as loading the image after the page is loaded.